# How to remove repeat properties in css?

Tags: css, scss-lint

I think it happens after git merge,

there are a lot of repeating in my css

for example here:

```
.case_wrap .same__text {
  margin: 90px 0 100px;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  position: relative;

}
```

some properties are different "position: relative || position: absolute" in one class

How can I clear it automatically??

Comment: Check if you don't have the classes more than once in the respective file. It looks like the code is coming from one file, not multiple, cause it would be separate and just overwrite the previous one, not as you presented it in your case.

Comment: if you are using git, you should be able to see the differences before and after merge.

Comment: some IDE plugins support highlighting for duplicate properties, you should use your IDE to find (and maybe auto-fix) them

Comment: Questions asking us to suggest, find or recommend a book, tool, software library, plug-in, tutorial, explain a technique or provide any other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: It shouldn't be a result of a merge first hand! When you've both relative and absolute, can you trace back the origin of these declarations? Do you work in a team, is it compiled/processed by Sass/LESS/Stylus/PostCSS? In a normal situation, you should use [stylelint](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/) which works with CSS, Scss and even CSS-in-JS, maybe their presets, maybe stylelint-order (I'm trying [this order](https://github.com/alsacreations/bretzel/blob/features/stylelint/.stylelintrc#L54-L180))